# I'm not able to create bucket in Amazon S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**This is content of my "config" file:**

```
[default]

region = us-west-1

output = json

[profile reader]

region = region=us-west-1

output = json

[profile writer]

region = region=us-west-1

output = json
```

**This is content of my "credentials" file**

```
[default]

aws_access_key_id = .....................J6O

aws_secret_access_key = .................PNM/a


[reader]

aws_access_key_id = .....................PPF

aws_secret_access_key = .................iPQ46


[writer]
aws_access_key_id = .....................J6O

aws_secret_access_key = .................PNM/a
```

This is command I use in AWS CLI:

```
C:\Users\Evgeni\.aws>aws s3 mb s3://rofl.easy-breezy.kek --profile=writer
```

When I try to run it, I have this error:

```
Invalid endpoint: https://s3.region=us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

But if I run it with specified --region parameter - it works fine:

```
C:\Users\Evgeni\.aws>aws s3 mb s3://yewfy.topkek.azaza44666 --profile=writer --region=us-west-1

make_bucket: yewfy.topkek.azaza44666
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your config file says

```
region = region=us-west-1
```

in two places. remove the extra `region=` from those lines

Comment: no shame at all. I make the same kind of mistake all the time. It's always easier to see those with a different pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 4):

You have typo in the config:

```
region = region=us-west-1
```